# Arabic Text shows in wrong-direction in Word, but not Google Docs

Tags: ms-word, arabic

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K33ug.png

I have a word document that shows Arabic text in the wrong direction to expected.

I opened the same doc on my colleagues machine and the text shows in the correct direction.

I uploaded the doc to Google Docs, which shows it in the correct direction.

When I copy and paste the wrong-direction-text from Word into another text-editor (not word), the text becomes the right direction.

Which settings do I not have within my Word that I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: check if you are installing the Arabic support on your operating system.

Comment: I think your question  should be asked in SuperUser not SO

Comment: I'm able to view the Arabic text, and have the language installed in both Word and Language Preferences within Control Panel. I'll ask the same question in SuperUser. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. Here's how I did it:

The Arabic language within Word had to be set as the Default language. By doing this, when pasting into Word the text was in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to align the text and make it right-to-left. 
If you noticed, you have it set as left-to-right.

There is also the issue of the letters not connecting together. Are you on a Mac?